# Optional param in react-router-dom route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was trying to get back to react-router-dom Route handling and found a use case that I'm not able to get around. Here's the summary of it.

I was thinking of creating a URL route like this : `http://localhost:3001/org/:area?/:id/:tabId?`.

```
<Route exact path='/org/:area?/:id/:tabId?'>
    ...
</Route>
```

When I am visiting the below urls, the dymamic values are not matching what I would want them to be.

1. http://localhost:3001/org/e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d

   **:area** = e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d
2. http://localhost:3001/org/e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d/XYinx

   **:area** = e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d

   **:id** = XYinx
3. http://localhost:3001/org/shop/e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d

   **:area** = shop

   **:id** = e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d
4. http://localhost:3001/org/shop/e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d/XYinx

   **:area** = shop

   **:id** = e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d

   **:tabId** = XYinx

Some contraints to the above route are:

a. "e439e39b-1974-4934-8570-a1bf68211a0d" has to be treated as **:id** in the url

b. "shop" has to be treated as **:area**

c. "XYinx" has to be treated as **:tabId**

Here as you see 1st and 2nd URLs are problematic as per this url structure. I also tried separating the two like this:

```
<Route exact path="/org/:area/:id/:tabId?">
    ...
</Route>

<Route exact path="/org/:id/:tabId?"}>
    ...
</Route>
```

but again here the problem is that the 2nd route will match the 1st URL as well. Do you guys have a better idea on how to handle this? Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Note: I am using v5 of react-router-dom and v17 for react.**

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters you can pass provide a regex for your match parameters.

It means that you should be able to do something like that:

```
const ID_REGEX = "[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}"

<Route exact path={`/org/:area/:id(${ID_REGEX})/:tabId?`}>
    ...
</Route>

<Route exact path={`/org/:id(${ID_REGEX})/:tabId?`}>
    ...
</Route>
```

Comment: My answer would be a variation of this, and not sufficiently different. It gets my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

because both paths have dynamic params under the same path "/org", then it will always go for the first one.

in that case, you will want to add a static param that will help identify the path.
here is an example of some options you can use:

```js
<route path="/org">
 <Route path=":id/:tabId?">
    ...
 </Route>
 <Route path="area/:area/:id/:tabId?">
    ...
 </Route>
</route>
```